# Bootstrap.css "font-family" on <body> tag crashed page on all IE versions! (windows7 64 bit machine)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I was using the updating version of bootstrap which is Bootstrap v2.3.1., and it crashed on IE, my machine is Windows 7 64 bit, and i've tried all my IE version browser, it all crashed, said "Internet Explorere restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX Controls" then i close this message, then the page just goes blank, which whatever default background color you have.

then i tried to take off the bootstrap.css, the website displays text etc on IE.
then i tried to go to http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html which is the offical site, it display the same error message on IE. other browsers all fine!

then i go back to the bootstrap.css, and try to debug it, i found that if i delete the line font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; from the  tag the site's showing on the IE screen! but of course the styling a bit messy, cause missing the font, but the page displays on IE finally!

Does anyone facing this issue before? and do you know how to fix this? it displays very ugly on IE, if i put back any font-family style, the page crashed again...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it appears to be the first two fonts that are causing the issue, I changed the attribute to....

font-family: Arial, sans-serif;

and it looks OK, provided you like Arial! if not try another font.

Answer (score 0):

I had been unable to use my IE on Windows 7 64 bit for almost a year.  It would switch to compatibility mode and then crash on almost 70% of websites that I visited.  After lots of troubleshooting and research I found that the Helvetica fonts installed on my machine were not completely compatible with Windows 7 or IE.  Since uninstalling the Helvetica fonts from my machine, IE has been working great.